# r - f951: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: r, gfortran, install.packages

I'm trying to install MVN package:

```
> install.packages("MVN")
probando la URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/MVN_5.5.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 382369 bytes (373 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 373 KB

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/79/xxghr9tj65789879v41wrp6h0000gn/T//Rtmp4bpod5/downloaded_packages
```

but when I do `library(MVN)` it says me that `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘MVN’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘rrcov’`

so when I try to install it:

```
> install.packages("rrcov")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
rrcov  1.4-4  1.4-7              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) yes
installing the source package ‘rrcov’

probando la URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rrcov_1.4-7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 965680 bytes (943 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 943 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rrcov’ ...
** package ‘rrcov’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c covOPW.c -o covOPW.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c ds11.f -o ds11.o
gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘15.6.0
f951: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4

f951: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6
gfortran: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program f951)
make: *** [ds11.o] Abort trap: 6
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rrcov’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rrcov’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rrcov’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/79/xxghr9tj65789879v41wrp6h0000gn/T/Rtmp4bpod5/downloaded_packages’
```

I've searched how to fix that, installing XCode, reinstalling r, and nothing. I need this package to perfom some multivariate analysis for my thesis but I do not know how to fix it.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

I am using an iOS 10.11.6

Comment: Looks like you have a wrong binary version of gfortran.

Comment: what happens if you type no and try to install the earlier binary version that doesnt need compilation?

Comment: @gfgm how can I type that? like this?: `install_version("rrcov", version = "1.4-5")` but it looks doesn't work: `Error in download_version_url(package, version, repos, type) :   version '1.4-5' is invalid for package 'rrcov'`

Comment: Why are you trying 1.4-5 when above it clearly offers you the binary  1.4-4. I know nothing about rrcov, but it is just written in your question where you were asked to answer YES or NO. Just try answering NO.

Comment: Solved, it is as you said @VladimirF, I typed NO and it works.. Thanks!!!